# Как скруглить края у ListView?

Tags: android, listview, java

**Вопрос следующий:**
Есть разметка `RelativeLayout` внутри которой расположен `ListView` c отступами по краям. Так вот при заполнении списка `ListView` имеет естественно прямоугольную форму, что чисто эстетически меня не удовлетворяет!

Хотел узнать как можно скруглить края `ListView` на андроид.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не делайте из андроида iOS, следуйте гайдлайнам. А по сабжу — android:background + shape drawable.

Comment: В таком случае будут скругдятся края всех элементов ListView, а я хочу скруглить края только самого контейнера! Скругление - это не моя прихоть, а выдумки дизайнера скрекпленные подписью заказчика! А дизайнеры будто никогда от айфонов и не отходили! Весь дизайн под айос а мне его подстраивать под андроид приходится!

Comment: Так вы и применяйте background к самому ListView, а не к его элементам. А по поводу дизайнеров — до боли знакомая ситуация. :)

Comment: Ну я к нему и применяю! При нажатии на верхний элемент в таком варианте фон элемента убивает фон ListView, а если при этом применять в фоновый рисунок в варианте с ненажатым элементом ListView то он автоматом убивает основной фон, в смысле загромождает!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте обернуть `ListView` каким-нибудь Layout и ему назначить нужный `background`. Для `ListView` же можно поставить `android:cacheColorHind` в `@android:color/transparent`.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже не очень приветствую делать из андрюши яблоко, но приходится....

в Вашем случае я поступаю так:

есть 4 файла-картинки для бэкграунда ячейки **ListView**: для центральной ячейки, для верхней,для нижней, для случая, когда ячейка всего 1 (у нее все 4 края закруглены). последние 3 с закругленными краями (на самом деле картинки сами по себе прямоугольные, просто по краям альфа-канал поэтому создается эффект закругления)

в адаптере я программно в методе **getView**, зная поцизию текущего элемента и общее количество элементов в списке, выставляю вьюхе нужный бэкграунд.

Comment: вот именно что я не знаю кол-во элементов, т.к. листвью заполняется из массива распарсенного из джейсон файла. Можно конечно поставить оператор который будет вычислять по урл ленф и выдавать! Но все это опять же работа с drawable ресурсами! Неужели нельзя изменить форму самого контейнера?

Comment: как это Вы не знаете количество элементов в массиве? а метод адаптера getCount() зачем тогда?
помнится в свое время я эту тему курил усиленно и в итоге пришел только к этому решению, поскольку оно идеально дает нужный результат.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь CardView из support-v7:21 либы от гугла. Используйте CardView как контейнер списку.

В CardView можно задать скругление углов.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="?cardBackGroundColor"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```